# rm the current directory you are in and issues surrounding it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

If I cd to a directory, is there a quick way to delete the directory I am in and move to the top directory? Usually I cd to a directory, ls it and then cd .. then delete the folder. I want to be able to cd to it and ls. Then if I just want to delete it from there.

Basically is there a rm operator that equates `rm -r $(pwd); cd ..`

Also, how come if I do not add `; cd ..` bash will still believe it is in the directory that doesn't exist?

```
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop$ mkdir test
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop$ cd test
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ touch test
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ ls
test
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ rm -r $(pwd)
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ pwd
/home/michaelxu/Desktop/test
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ touch test
touch: cannot touch `test': No such file or directory
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop/test$ cd ..
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~/Desktop$ cd test
-bash: cd: test: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It behaves like it's in a directory that doesn't exist because that's exactly what is happening. It still has a pointer to that directory, but that pointer is no longer valid. `bash` doesn't know that the directory has been deleted.

Comment: Part of what’s happening is that `bash` probably doesn’t check to see what directory it’s in after every command, but only after every `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd`.  It depends on exactly how you have defined `PS1`.  For example, try `cd test` and then `mv ../test ../quiz` (or `(cd ..; mv test quiz)`).  The prompt will probably still say `Desktop/test`, because `bash` has no reason to check whether the directory name has changed.                //                P.S. May I suggest that you don’t use the same name (`test`) for two different things in your examples?

Answer (score 0):

Under bash:

```
rm -rf "$(pwd -P)" && cd ..
```